# server can't recognize CentOS6.5 booting USB-disk burned with `dd` command

Tags: centos6, usb-boot

I burned a boot USBkey with the command(from [CentOS wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey)):

```
dd if=CentOS-6.5-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

After the command, I found my USBkey has beened wipe all partitions and it showed entirely freespace of my USB. However, I could find the USB-booting option in my computer's BIOS after rebooting and it shows the installation UI, and thus I think it will work on server too.

So I reboot my server `lenovo x3650m5`(PS: I have found that [RHEL6 support the server](https://access.redhat.com/ecosystem/hardware/1253393), so `CentOS` is supposed to support it), but it failed-it found the USB, but it couldn't load the booting system.

Did I miss anything needed for the boot operation on the server?

Comment: Is the USB stick defective or counterfeit?

Comment: @MichaelHampton No, it's legal `Kingston Data Traveler SE9`, and finnally  it worked after I had to turn to `rufus` on windows to reburn it.  I'm just wondering if it's the formal solution from [CenOS Wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey), and I follow the solution, why failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is the server can't recognize any bootinUSB burned by `dd`, and I finnally walked around the problem by using `rufus` to burn again on win10.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard people say that some USB sticks boot after `dd` and some don't, and have had the same experience myself - seems some combinations of USB/motherboard work, and some don't.

Try a different USB stick.